# Admin Redirect 2.3.4

Tags: admin, redirect

I have 3 stores in my Magento setup, each one going to a unique URL (they share products across all three).  I was using version 2.3.1 and everything worked great.  When I went to the admin on any of the three, it redirected me to my "default" URL/admin.

I just upgraded to 2.3.4 and the following is happening:
Store #1 - goes to proper URL
Store #2 - goes to proper URL
Store #3 (same as default store) - goes to Store #1 URL

Entering the admin path tries to direct me to store #1 url/admin, which in turn tries to direct me to the "default" url/admin, but because of the redirect problem it tries to go to store #1 url/admin... causing a timeout due to never ending redirects.

I know something has been changed in my db, probably in core_config but I can't find it for the life of me.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the issue introduced by the Core Team.
Just configure once again the separate domain for Custom Domain for Admin Panel

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem, here is the fix.  In the database there is a store_website table.  In that table is all of the stores and associated websites.  My problem was that the default setting was for the wrong website, so I was putting myself into an indefinite redirect.  Once I changed this to the proper site, everything works well.

As an FYI, v2.3.2 must not look at this table / setting because I never had a problem before, even though I could see it was set wrong there as well.